# How to retrieve public Google document without login using API?

Tags: c#, .net, google-docs

I had shared some documents to public on web. Is there any way to use Google API to retrieve these documents without login?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Trying to do this without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I do it for my document:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) {
    string priceList=wc.DownloadString("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?hl=en_US&hl=en_US&key=0Aic3jYFcLTrldEhQU1dDTzdTdFBhaVA4OGtPX2FUMUE&single=true&gid=0&output=txt");
    string[] lines = priceList.Split('\n');
}
```

This will get a Spreadsheet in a text format to the variable `priceList`.

Comment: What if the line ending is `\n\r`? At the beginning of every line would be a stray `\r`. And what if the file is created on Unix (`\r`)?

Comment: You will then filter that character out or use different .Split override.  Create a new question for that, as it isn't directly related to this one here.

Comment: Added my answer. Also, you forgot .Dispose() or an using block

Answer (score 0):

What you would do is

```
// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx
WebClient wc = new WebClient();

// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144200.aspx
string priceList=wc.DownloadString(
    new Uri(
        "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?hl=en_US&hl=en_US&key=0Aic3jYFcLTrldEhQU1dDTzdTdFBhaVA4OGtPX2FUMUE&single=true&gid=0&output=txt");

// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3cc9y48w.aspx
wc.Dispose(); // Free resources

// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx
string[] lines = priceList.Split(
    new string[] {
        "\r\n",
        "\n\r", // Rarely ever used, but be prepared
        "\n" // Match this and
        "\r" }, // this last
StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: Honestly, I believe it's overkill. Technically, calling the same web service would return the same new line char on every document it produces.

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Does Google API allow us to access a public document without login?

Answer (score 0):

If you have shared document with public access you can share its download URL to download it without login into google. To build download URL **through google api** you need to have resource Id for that particular document.

For more information have a look at this : [Google Docs : Download Documents and files](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#downloading_documents_and_files)

Comment: I have been trying to do that. Following Google's documentation doesn't result in a public URL that you can use. Google's sample create an stream inside .NET, they do not provide the URL that you can use independently. Need more detail here. Thanks.